# Conditionally set flag in Dockerfile CMD instruction

Tags: docker, dockerfile

At the end of my dockerfile I have a `CMD` instruction:

```
CMD ['my_script.sh', '--debug']
```

But I want the `debug` flag to be optional, chosen at build time. My solution to this is to use a build arg, i.e.

```
ARG DEBUG=""
CMD ["my_script.sh", "$DEBUG"]
```

Then building with either

```
docker image build --build-arg='--debug' ...etc
```

or

```
docker image build ...etc
```

With the first option, the image builds successfully, but when running a container I get the following error:

```
Invalid option '$DEBUG'
```

The double-quotes must be causing the command to literally use the string `$DEBUG`. But changing things so that `$DEBUG` is in single quotes or in no quotes gets

```
/bin/sh: [my_script.sh,: No such file or directory
```

Finally, using

```
CMD ./my_script.sh $DEBUG
```

successfully runs the container but ignores `$DEBUG`

Am I doing anything wrong? Is there a better solution? Is there any solution at all?

Comment: Of course there is a better way, make `my_script.sh` an entrypoint, not CMD. Then when running the image you can simply pass your env as a run argument: `docker run your/image $DEBUG`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `$DEBUG` is only known at the build time. So if you want it to be resolved at the container runtime you can set `ENV` variable from your DEBUG `ARG` as a workaround :

```
ARG DEBUG=""
ENV DEBUG ${DEBUG}
CMD ["sh", "-c", "my_script.sh $DEBUG"]
```

This way you will have an environment variable called `DEBUG` which will have value from `ARG DEBUG` and this environment variable will be accessible from the cmd.

However I think that you could use environment variable only - there is no need for build arg for that. You can then pass environment variable value to the container using `-e` option. For example empty `DEBUG` env variable :

```
docker container run -e DEBUG image_name
```

or with value :

```
docker container run -e DEBUG=--debug image_name
```

Comment: This was close, but I had to change the `CMD` to `CMD ["sh", "-c", "my_script.sh $DEBUG"]`. Could you note that in your answer?